# Same db context multiple ToTable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, dbset

I have a product configuration as such:

```
internal sealed class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ProductConfiguration"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ProductConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        // Configure Properties
        HasKey(n => new { n.ID });

        // Specify the name of the table to get the data from
        ToTable("vw_Products");
    }
}
```

Which I can then get using the context

```
public IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Which all works well.  However, I have a part of the site that is using a filtered set of the products and it is faster to use a new view to filter the products rather than filtering them with entity framework (under 1 second instead of 5 seconds using a linq query in ef)

Is there a way I can change the `ToTable` value only for a certain instance of trying to get a filtered context without having to create a new entity.

So for example, where I get the products -

```
context.Products
```

Can I change the table for this to look at the new view?

I have tried copying the configuration to look at the new view and then added a new dbset as such:

```
public IDbSet<Product> DesignerProducts { get; set; }
```

But this doesn't seem to work (unless there is a way to point the configuration at that particular dbset?)

So I guess my question is, is there a way to point the configuration at a particular dbset (if the entity is the same) or is there a way to point the context at a particular view when it is queried

In effect I am wanting a context with the following 2 dbsets:

```
public IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public IDbSet<Product> DesignerProducts { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't think it is possible to achieve what I want so in order to get around it I have had to make a new context and put my new filtered list into that instead.  If anyone can think of a better way to do this then please feel free to post an answer